# Amazon Athena gives Internal Error while parsing nested JSON

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I'm trying to query this JSON file (for debugging purposes it contains only one row!):

```
{
  "appVersion": null,
  "sessionIndex": "3",
  "psdkLang": null,
  "lamdbaAwsRequestId": "bb04330c-e1e7-4bbd-97b8-86fdb2ee0b7f",
  "bundleID": "xyz",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2017-03-31T01:45:30.796Z",
  "type": "logEvent",
  "userIdfv": null,
  "osVersion": null,
  "uniqueIndex": "9c6c3927-aa66-4974-adac-fd10fc83a1e5",
  "userIdfa": null,
  "eventName": "Rewarded Ads Ad Is Ready",
  "deviceType": null,
  "eventId": "shardId-000000000005:49571690399037302251611429510623174446442870333536993362",
  "store1": "google",
  "deviceLang": null,
  "geoCode": null,
  "sessionId": "34B4CEC8-9AA0-40DD-94C4-C5420F563F68",
  "params": "{\"AdProvider\":\"AdColony\",\"AdIsReady\":\"false\"}",
  "gameVersion": null,
  "internetConnectionState": null,
  "deviceModel": null,
  "deviceTimeZone": null,
  "time": "2017-03-31T10:44:50.117+0900",
  "userId": "24176983"
}
```

I created a table in Amazon Athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RV_QA.RAAIR (
  `appversion` string,
  `psdklang` string,
  `bundleid` string,
  `receivetimestamp` string,
  `type` string,
  `osversion` string,
  `store1` string,
  `devicelang` string,
  `geocode` string,
  `sessionid` string,
  `eventName` string,
  `params` map<string,string>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'  
) LOCATION 's3://...'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

When I run this query:
`select eventname from RAAIR;`
everything works.

When I try to use the nested JSON (params element):
`select params['AdIsReady'] from RAAIR;`
I get an "Internal error" message.

What am I missing here?

Comment: perhaps the error log? :-)

Comment: Nothing from the error log.
After a long study I found that the problem is in the params element: its value is escaped - \" instead of " and Athena doesn't know how to handle it. Is there any way to tell Athena to ignore this escape char?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, I found the problem. The question now is what's the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment that `params` includes backslashes for escaping.
This is because `params` is a string, not a nested object.  Athena is not able to make a MAP directly from a string, so you get the "Internal error" messages.

If you cannot change the data to have params as a nested object, you can change the table definition so `params` is a string:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RV_QA.RAAIR (
  ...
  `params` string
)
...
```

Athena (Presto) will allow you to parse the JSON in the string and query out values.
There are at least two different ways to do this by parsing, casting, and extracting values at your preference:

```
SELECT
  CAST(json_parse(params) as MAP(varchar, varchar))['AdIsReady'] as AdIsReady1,
  json_extract_scalar(json_parse(params), '$.AdIsReady') as AdIsReady2
FROM RV_QA.RAAIR LIMIT 10;
```